# Vectors in layer not displaying but can select all and are shown in Attribute Table

Tags: qgis-3

I am working in 3.4.13 and having issues with vectors in a layer doesn't display.

I can select all and are shown in the Attribute Table but are not visible

I am very new to GIS.

Comment: To look at the more commun problem made sure that your layer is not hidden under another layer, try to zoom to extend, check for CRS issue and check your symbology (no transparent or to small to be seen symbol) then give us more detail on your setting if nothing solve your problem

Comment: It's not hidden under another layer, opacity set to 100%.